# A top-like live monitor for virsh/kvm/qemu VM's

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, curses

I needed a tool to monitor VM's running on my server in relatively real-time (similar to `top` or the many variants out there). The main things I need to keep track of are:

- All VM's listed via `virsh list --all`;

  ```
   Id    Name                           State
  ----------------------------------------------------
   13    Experiments-Proxy              running
   -     Experiments-PHP                shut off
   -     Experiments-Python             shut off
  ```
- All networks listed via `virsh net-list --all`;

  ```
   Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
  ----------------------------------------------------------
   default              inactive   yes           yes
   net_10_1_1_0         active     yes           yes
   net_10_1_2_0         active     yes           yes
   net_10_1_3_0         active     yes           yes
  ```
- All storage pools listed via `virsh pool-list --all`;

  ```
   Name                 State      Autostart
  -------------------------------------------
   Experiments          active     yes
   images               active     yes
  ```

To do this, I built a small Python script using curses that effectively does three things:

1. Lists all the aforementioned components;
2. Updates the list on a regular basis (every 2 seconds, basically);
3. Allows basic management of the aforementioned components (start, stop);

All of this is rather simple, if long and convoluted.

To start with, I built a function that runs the `virsh` command with the arguments I need to. I discarded the error output because I honestly don't care about it for this tool.

```
def virsh(command, arg):
    out, _ = subprocess.Popen(['virsh', command, arg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()
    out = re.split('[\r\n]+', out.decode("utf-8"))
    return list(map(lambda line: list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.split('\\s{2,}', line))), out))
```

This allows me to do something like the following further on in the script:

```
vms = virsh('list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
nets = virsh('net-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
pools = virsh('pool-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
```

Next, I needed a way to print a table in curses. This went relatively smooth as well, as all I did was push a list of columns and items into a function, with a few extra parameters:

```
def print_table(stdscr, head_color, sel_color, sel_i, x, y, cols, gray_sel, items):
    total_len = sum(list(map(lambda col: col[1] + 1, cols)))
    stdscr.insstr(y, x, ' ' * total_len, head_color)
    col_offset = 0

    if sel_i > -1:
        stdscr.addstr(y + sel_i + 1, x, ' ' * total_len, sel_color)

    c = 0
    for (name, minsize, gray) in cols:
        stdscr.addstr(y, x + col_offset, name, head_color)

        i = 1
        for item in items:
            color_offset = 1 if sel_i == (i - 1) else 0
            color = curses.color_pair(color_offset)
            gray_color = curses.color_pair(color_offset + (3 if gray_sel(item) else 0))
            stdscr.addstr(y + i, x + col_offset, item[c], gray_color if gray else color)
            i += 1
        col_offset += minsize + 1
        c += 1
```

Next, I needed to print a "help" at the bottom of the screen. For this I simply list each keystroke / command, and a single word about what it does. I might have a list like `[("TAB", "Next"), ("F1", "Start"), ("F2", "Stop"), ("F10", "Quit")]`:

```
def print_help(stdscr, help_color, helps):
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    stdscr.insstr(height - 1, 0, ' ' * width, help_color)
    max_len = max(list(map(lambda x: len(x[1]), helps))) + 1
    offset = 0
    for (key, name) in helps:
        stdscr.insstr(height - 1, offset, key)
        stdscr.insstr(height - 1, offset + len(key), name, help_color)
        offset += len(key) + max_len
```

The next step is running all the logic to render the screen. For this, I built a `render` function that takes all the parameters I need:

```
def set_x_for_yes(x): return 'X' if x == 'yes' else ' '


def render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i):
    pool_diff = 2
    longest_net = max(list(map(lambda net: len(net[0]), nets)))
    longest_pool = max(list(map(lambda pool: len(pool[0]), pools)))
    longest_net = max(longest_net, longest_pool - pool_diff)
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    net_offset = width - longest_net - 9 - pool_diff - 3
    vm_width = net_offset - 3 - 9 - 1 - 2

    vm_table = [("ID", 3, False), ("VM", vm_width - 1, True), ("STATUS", 9, False)]
    net_table = [("NET", longest_net, True), ("STATUS", 8, False), ("A", 1, False), ("P", 1, False)]
    pool_table = [("POOL", longest_net + pool_diff, True), ("STATUS", 8, False), ("A", 1, False)]
    nets = list(map(lambda net: [net[0], net[1], set_x_for_yes(net[2]), set_x_for_yes(net[3])], nets))
    pools = list(map(lambda pool: [pool[0], pool[1], set_x_for_yes(pool[2])], pools))

    tables = [
        (0, 0, 0, vm_table, lambda vm: vm[2] != "running", vms),
        (1, net_offset, 0, net_table, lambda net: net[1] != "active", nets),
        (2, net_offset, len(nets) + 2, pool_table, lambda pool: pool[1] != "active", pools)
    ]

    head_color = curses.color_pair(2)
    sel_color = curses.color_pair(1)
    for (sel_c, x, y, table, sel_test, items) in tables:
        print_table(stdscr, head_color, sel_color, sel_i if sel == sel_c else -1, x, y, table, sel_test, items)

    print_help(
        stdscr,
        curses.color_pair(1),
        [("TAB", "Next"), ("F1", "Start"), ("F2", "Stop"), ("F10", "Quit")])
```

This builds up all the components to pass to the rendering functions.

Lastly, I have a `main` function that I use `curses.wrapper` to run. This allows curses to setup all the screen components, and clean the screen up when it ends (either with success or failure):

```
def main(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    curses.halfdelay(20)
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()
    curses.init_pair(1, 0, 6)
    curses.init_pair(2, 0, 2)
    curses.init_pair(3, 8, -1)
    curses.init_pair(4, 8, 6)
    sel = 0
    sel_i = 0

    start_commands = ['start', 'net-start', 'pool-start']
    stop_commands = ['destroy', 'net-destroy', 'pool-destroy']

    while True:
        vms = virsh('list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
        nets = virsh('net-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
        pools = virsh('pool-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]

        args = [vms, nets, pools]
        arg_indexes = [1, 0, 0]

        stdscr.clear()
        render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i)
        stdscr.refresh()
        c = stdscr.getch()

        if c == curses.KEY_F10:
            exit()
        elif c == ord('\t'):
            sel = 0 if sel == 2 else sel + 1
        elif c == curses.KEY_DOWN or c == curses.KEY_UP:
            sel_i += -1 if c == curses.KEY_UP else 1
        elif (c == curses.KEY_F1 or c == curses.KEY_F2) and sel_i < len(args[sel]):
            commands = stop_commands if c == curses.KEY_F2 else start_commands
            virsh(commands[sel], args[sel][sel_i][arg_indexes[sel]])

        if sel_i == -1:
            sel_i += 1
        if sel_i >= len(args[sel]):
            sel_i = len(args[sel]) - 1


curses.wrapper(main)
```

This also has all the key-handling logic to adjust the scene.

I have yet to set up scrolling on each table, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Once all is said and done, running the script gives me an output of the following:

[image: virsh-monitor result]

Any and all comments welcome. I don't have any PEP-8 flags in PyChar, so I'm thinking I'm already off to a good start here.

Comment: Not using the libvirt Python API?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Didn't know there was one, but that would make a valid answer. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately Python is not a language I'm particularly strong in, so I may have to pass that on to someone else.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If you're interested, I posted an answer converting this to the libvirt API

Comment: Is this something you're willing to release in a public repo? I'd be interested in using it if you do

Comment: @CanadianLuke I actually already did ;) https://github.com/ellersoft/virsh-monitor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Bugs

There was one bug if no networks or pools existed, then calculation of `longest_net` and `longest_pool` respectively would fail, since `max()` would be called on an empty list.  The solution is to add a `default` kw-arg

```
-    longest_net = max(len(net.name()) for net in nets)
-    longest_pool = max(len(pool.name()) for pool in pools)
+    longest_net = max((len(net.name()) for net in nets), default=0)
+    longest_pool = max((len(pool.name()) for pool in pools), default=0)
```

## Use libvirt API

Based on @MichaelHampton's advice I moved the code to the libvirt API, basing off of the changes made in [the answer by @Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/244398/85095).

The crucial difference is to make a connection to libvirt in `__main__` (otherwise we'd run into problems with interactive authentication on the console if curses already initialised):

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
-    curses.wrapper(main)
+    conn = libvirt.open(None)
+    curses.wrapper(main, conn)
```

Then in `main(stdscr, conn)`:

```
     while True:
-        vms = virsh('list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
-        nets = virsh('net-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
-        pools = virsh('pool-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
+        vms = conn.listAllDomains()
+        nets = conn.listAllNetworks()
+        pools = conn.listAllStoragePools()
```

Other than that it's just moving away from array-of-strings to method calls on libvirt objects, e.g.:

```
-    longest_net = max(len(net[0]) for net in nets)
-    longest_pool = max(len(pool[0]) for pool in pools)
+    longest_net = max((len(net.name()) for net in nets))
+    longest_pool = max((len(pool.name()) for pool in pools))
```

I also needed to create a 'vms' array just like the 'pools' and 'nets' array for `print_table` now.  As this function however operates much on strings while the API returns integer constants, the least-effort approach taken by me was to convert all integers to strings via dictionaries and not touch `print_table` itself.  Particularly `virDomain.state()` returns `[state, reason]` with both being integers;  in order to pretty-print this I created a dictionary which then can be used like this:

```python
state_string = {
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_NOSTATE: 'nostate',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_RUNNING: 'running',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCKED: 'blocked',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_PAUSED: 'paused',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTDOWN: 'shutdown',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTOFF: 'shutoff',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_CRASHED: 'crashed',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_PMSUSPENDED: 'pmsuspended',
}
print(state_string[vm.state()[0]])
```

Similarly, the start/stop is handled via objects which reads much better:

```
-            commands = stop_commands if c == curses.KEY_F2 else start_commands
-            virsh(commands[sel], args[sel][sel_i][arg_indexes[sel]])
+            if c == curses.KEY_F2:
+                args[sel][sel_i].destroy()
+            else:
+                args[sel][sel_i].create()
```

## Add other hypervisors

As we are now using the libvirt API, it's quite easy to add support for accessing other hypervisors via URI. I used `getopt` to parse a `-c URI` CLI argument:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
-    conn = libvirt.open(None)
+    import sys
+    import getopt
+    try:
+        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'c:')
+    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
+        print(err)
+        sys.exit(1)
+
+    uri = None
+    for o, a in opts:
+        if o == '-c':
+            uri = a
+
+    try:
+        conn = libvirt.open(uri)
+    except libvirt.libvirtError:
+        print('Failed to open connection to the hypervisor')
+        sys.exit(1)
+
     curses.wrapper(main, conn)
```

This allows to monitor remote hypervisor instances or the system one, e.g.:

```
$ ./virtop.py -c 'qemu+ssh://username@ip.of.vm.host/system'
```

## Final code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import libvirt
import curses

state_string = {
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_NOSTATE: 'nostate',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_RUNNING: 'running',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCKED: 'blocked',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_PAUSED: 'paused',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTDOWN: 'shutdown',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_SHUTOFF: 'shutoff',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_CRASHED: 'crashed',
    libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_PMSUSPENDED: 'pmsuspended',
}

active_string = {
    0: 'inactive',
    1: 'active',
}


def print_table(stdscr, head_color, sel_color, sel_i, x, y, cols, gray_sel, items):
    total_len = sum(col[1] + 1 for col in cols)
    stdscr.insstr(y, x, ' ' * total_len, head_color)
    if sel_i > -1:
        stdscr.addstr(y + sel_i + 1, x, ' ' * total_len, sel_color)

    for c, (name, minsize, gray) in enumerate(cols):
        stdscr.addstr(y, x, name, head_color)
        for i, item in enumerate(items, 1):
            color = curses.color_pair(
                (sel_i == (i - 1))
                + (3 if gray and gray_sel(item) else 0)
            )
            stdscr.addstr(y + i, x, item[c], color)
        x += minsize + 1


def print_help(stdscr, help_color, helps):
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    stdscr.insstr(height - 1, 0, ' ' * width, help_color)
    max_len = max(len(h[1]) for h in helps) + 1
    offset = 0
    for key, name in helps:
        stdscr.insstr(height - 1, offset, key)
        stdscr.insstr(height - 1, offset + len(key), name, help_color)
        offset += len(key) + max_len


def set_x_if_true(x):
    return 'X' if x else ' '


def render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i):
    pool_diff = 2
    longest_net = max((len(net.name()) for net in nets), default=0)
    longest_pool = max((len(pool.name()) for pool in pools), default=0)
    longest_net = max(longest_net, longest_pool - pool_diff)
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    net_offset = width - longest_net - 9 - pool_diff - 3
    vm_width = net_offset - 3 - 9 - 1 - 2

    vm_table = [("ID", 3, False), ("VM", vm_width - 1, True), ("STATUS", 9, False)]
    net_table = [("NET", longest_net, True), ("STATUS", 8, False), ("A", 1, False), ("P", 1, False)]
    pool_table = [("POOL", longest_net + pool_diff, True), ("STATUS", 8, False), ("A", 1, False)]
    vms = [
        ['-' if vm.ID() == -1 else str(vm.ID()), vm.name(), state_string[vm.state()[0]]]
        for vm in vms
    ]
    nets = [
        [net.name(), active_string[net.isActive()], set_x_if_true(net.autostart()), set_x_if_true(net.isPersistent())]
        for net in nets
    ]
    pools = [
        [pool.name(), active_string[pool.isActive()], set_x_if_true(pool.autostart())]
        for pool in pools
    ]

    tables = [
        (0, 0, 0, vm_table, lambda vm: vm[2] != state_string[libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_RUNNING], vms),
        (1, net_offset, 0, net_table, lambda net: net[1] != active_string[1], nets),
        (2, net_offset, len(nets) + 2, pool_table, lambda pool: pool[1] != active_string[1], pools)
    ]

    head_color = curses.color_pair(2)
    sel_color = curses.color_pair(1)
    for (sel_c, x, y, table, sel_test, items) in tables:
        print_table(stdscr, head_color, sel_color, sel_i if sel == sel_c else -1, x, y, table, sel_test, items)

    print_help(
        stdscr,
        curses.color_pair(1),
        [("TAB", "Next"), ("F1", "Start"), ("F2", "Stop"), ("F10", "Quit")]
    )


def main(stdscr, conn):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    curses.halfdelay(20)
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()
    curses.init_pair(1, 0, 6)
    curses.init_pair(2, 0, 2)
    curses.init_pair(3, 8, -1)
    curses.init_pair(4, 8, 6)
    sel = 0
    sel_i = 0

    while True:
        vms = conn.listAllDomains()
        nets = conn.listAllNetworks()
        pools = conn.listAllStoragePools()

        args = [vms, nets, pools]
        arg_indexes = [1, 0, 0]

        stdscr.clear()
        render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i)
        stdscr.refresh()
        c = stdscr.getch()

        if c == curses.KEY_F10:
            exit()
        elif c == ord('\t'):
            sel = 0 if sel == 2 else sel + 1
        elif c == curses.KEY_DOWN or c == curses.KEY_UP:
            sel_i += -1 if c == curses.KEY_UP else 1
        elif (c == curses.KEY_F1 or c == curses.KEY_F2) and sel_i < len(args[sel]):
            if c == curses.KEY_F2:
                args[sel][sel_i].destroy()
            else:
                args[sel][sel_i].create()

        if sel_i == -1:
            sel_i += 1
        if sel_i >= len(args[sel]):
            sel_i = len(args[sel]) - 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import getopt
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'c:')
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(1)

    uri = None
    for o, a in opts:
        if o == '-c':
            uri = a

    try:
        conn = libvirt.open(uri)
    except libvirt.libvirtError:
        print('Failed to open connection to the hypervisor')
        sys.exit(1)

    curses.wrapper(main, conn)
```

## Remarks

This code is now with almost no error handling and since the libvirt functions may throw exceptions quite often (e.g. when starting if it's already started), this needs to be addressed.  Also a `usage()` function documenting the `-c` option would be nice, I was too lazy for that. :-)

I'm personally not so proficient with python and more a C person, so the code might not be the most pythonic.

Also I can only recommend you looking into virt-manager which is basically what you did here.  While it's a GUI solution it allows connecting to remote instances, so your server does not need to run X or Wayland, although a virt-manager-tui would be cool as well.

Comment: There's also virt-top, which is much less colorful but displays some more information. I tried this code and found that it was slow to respond visually to keyboard input when connected to a remote hypervisor (on another continent). I expect you're loading information about whatever is being selected before updating the display. Other than that it looks really good.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh, I didn't know about virt-top, but it's not packaged for my distribution (as some dependencies such as libvirt-ocaml aren't either) and seems to be unmaintained anyhow. Ideally one should split input-handling from the model/information a bit better, right now it's difficult to fix that issue. Perhaps __someone__ eventually will pickup on this again. virt-top for reference: http://git.annexia.org/?p=virt-top.git;a=summary

Comment: @MichaelHampton That issue is because I use `curses.halfdelay(20)` as my timing loop (it waits until 2 seconds or keypress on every `.getch()` call), and my `stdscr.getch()` is only called once, then regardless of whether a use typed a key or not it reloads all the VMs, Networks, and Storage Pools. Going to play with that today, see if I can't speed the rendering up.

Answer (score 14):

### Subprocess

```
out, _ = subprocess.Popen(['virsh', command, arg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()
```

is a little clunky; consider

```
def virsh(*args):
    out = subprocess.check_output(('virsh', *args))
```

This will also:

- check for the error level after execution
- allow for an arbitrary number of command-line arguments

### Comprehensions

Let's see if we can translate this:

```
list(
    map(
        lambda line: list(
            map(
                lambda x: x.strip(), re.split('\\s{2,}', line)
            )
        ), 
        out
    )
)
```

from the old functional style to the new comprehension style. I also had to expand the above because it was a golfed nightmare.

```
[
    [
        x.strip()
        for x in re.split(r'\s{2,}', line)
    ]
    for line in out
]
```

Also note the use of a raw string for your regex.

Similarly, this:

```
sum(list(map(lambda col: col[1] + 1, cols)))
```

can be

```
sum(col[1] + 1 for col in cols)
```

### Type hints

This:

```
def print_table(stdscr, head_color, sel_color, sel_i, x, y, cols, gray_sel, items):
```

could really benefit from them. For instance, maybe `x` and `y` are `x: int, y: int`.

### Enumerate

```
    i = 1
    for item in items:
        # ...
        i += 1
```

should be

```
for i, item in enumerate(items):
```

### Implicit tuple unpack

```
for (name, minsize, gray) in cols:
```

does not need parens.

### Else-after-exit

```
        exit()
    elif c == ord('\t'):
```

does not need an `elif`; an `if` will suffice.

Comment: 2 nitpicks—1. nothing wrong with the functional style *except* forcing the generators to materialize as lists; I would let everything be lazy where possible (and formatting helps, too). 2. The elif does a far better job conveying the *structure* of the program, even if an if would suffice. Just at a glance, and elif chain tells me I dont have to examine in detail every branch to find the control flow.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  Re. lazy - I was aiming for direct equivalence, where a generator would not be. The OP uses the outputs of that comprehension in `render` in a manner incompatible with a generator since they're consumed more than once.

Comment: fair enough: didn’t read that part too closely.

Answer (score 10):

## Style

Your style is quite good, but you can tell that the code isn't written by a Pythonista.

- Whilst line length can be a touchy subject, it's mostly left at 79 if you follow PEP 8 or 90 if you're running Black.
  This is causing me to have a suboptimal experience editing your code.
- Defining functions on one line, like `set_x_for_yes`, are normally big no-nos.
- I'm not a fan of your single letter variables. But I'm also not entirely sure what I'd replace most of them with.
- (Potential religious war) The 'Pythonic' form of `list(map(...))` is a list comprehension.
  For example in `virsh` we can use:

  > ```py
  > return list(map(lambda line: list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.split('\\s{2,}', line))), out))
  > ```

  ```py
  return [
      [x.strip() for x in re.split('\\s{2,}', line)]
      for line in out
  ]
  ```
- Like most interpreted languages there is no 'main' entry point.
  As the code is interpreted from top to bottom.
  However sometimes we don't want code to run if it is not the 'main' script.
  To deal with this we can use an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard to prevent this code running if you import it.
- Python is quite allergic to chaining, and so it's common for the `subprocess.Popen` and `.communicate()` chain to be split across two assignments.

  ```py
  proc = subprocess.Popen(
      ['virsh', command, arg],
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
      stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
  )
  out, _ = proc.communicate()
  ```
- Having unneeded parentheses are really discouraged as they impede readability.

## Changes

- In `print_table`, converting the iterator returned from `map` to a `list` is unneeded.
  Additionally we can opt to use a generator expression instead.
  This is the same as the list comprehension before except it is wrapped in parentheses `()` and builds a generator.
  Python has some sugar when a generator expression is the only argument to a function and lets you drop the double parentheses `()`.

  > ```py
  > sum(list(map(lambda col: col[1] + 1, cols)))
  > ```

  ```py
  sum(col[1] + 1 for col in cols)
  ```
- In `print_table`, it's nice to see you using the `' ' * total_len` sugar.
- In `print_table`, we can use `enumerate` rather than manually looping through `c` and `i`.

  ```py
  for i, item in enumerate(items, 1):
  ```
- In `print_table`, rather than using a turnery to build 1 or 0, you can just use `int`.
  I would also be surprised if the functions don't support taking a bool in-place for an integer.
- In `print_table`, `col_offset` is only ever used as `x + col_offset`. At which point you might as well just update `x`.
- In `print_table`, you can merge the `if grey else` turnery into the `gray_color` line to build the correct colour with less lines of code.

Additional changes not made to the below code:

- It would be nice to add an Enum to make building the colour pairs easier. By using an `IntFlag` we can get the benefits of it acting like an int and act like flags.
  However your current mapping makes this hard.
  I would change it so the last bit is to change if the colour is grey.

  ```py
  class Colours(enum.IntFlag):
      DEFAULT = 0
      GRAY = 1
      SELECT = 2
      HEAD = 4
  ```

  This has a couple of benefits:

  1. If you decide to later change what the values are it is easier.
  2. We can use `Colours.DEFAULT` or `Colours.SELECT | Colours.GRAY` to select the wanted colours.
  3. It means we can change `print_help` to not use magic numbers.
- In `render`, I would rearrange a lot of the table information.

  The following values never change:

  - Headers.
  - Which columns can be grey.
  - Mutations (`set_x_for_yes`) to the items.
  - Selecting grey rows, `gray_sel` / `sel_test`.

  Values that can change each run:

  - The x position.
  - The y position.
  - The items.
  - The width of each column.

  And so I would move all the constants outside of the function.
  We can join these two tables together with `zip`.
- In `print_table`, you can remove the need for the two calls to `stdscr.insstr` with the value `' ' * total_len` if you pad the values.

  ```py
  >>> '{1:<{0}}|{2:^{0}}|{3:>{0}}'.format(5, 1, 2, 3)
  '1    |  2  |    3'
  ```
- A lot of `print_table` is not actually about printing the table it's about colouring it correctly.
  I would build another function that correctly colours everything.

  - If we change each item to a tuple of the item's string and the item's colour than it is easier to print the entire table.
  - If we include the headers in this function we can format everything correctly, and make `print_table` a very simple nested for loop.

  ```py
  def select_colors(values, sel_i, gray_sel, grays):
      for i, row in enumerate(values):
          gray_row = gray_sel(row)
          new_row = []
          for item, gray in zip(row, grays):
              color = Colours.SELECT if sel_i == i else Colours.DEFAULT
              if gray_row and gray:
                  color |= Colours.GRAY
              if i == 0:
                  color = Colours.HEAD
              new_row.append((item, curses.color_pair(color)))
          yield new_row
  ```

```py
import subprocess
import re
import time
import curses


def virsh(command, arg):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ['virsh', command, arg],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    out, _ = proc.communicate()
    return [
        [
            x.strip()
            for x in re.split('\\s{2,}', line)
        ]
        for line in re.split('[\r\n]+', out.decode("utf-8"))
    ]


def print_table(stdscr, head_color, sel_color, sel_i, x, y, cols, gray_sel, items):
    total_len = sum(col[1] + 1 for col in cols)
    stdscr.insstr(y, x, ' ' * total_len, head_color)
    if sel_i > -1:
        stdscr.addstr(y + sel_i + 1, x, ' ' * total_len, sel_color)

    for c, (name, minsize, gray) in enumerate(cols):
        stdscr.addstr(y, x, name, head_color)
        for i, item in enumerate(items, 1):
            color = curses.color_pair(
                sel_i == (i - 1)
                + (3 if gray and gray_sel(item) else 0)
            )
            stdscr.addstr(y + i, x, item[c], color)
        x += minsize + 1


def print_help(stdscr, help_color, helps):
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    stdscr.insstr(height - 1, 0, ' ' * width, help_color)
    max_len = max(len(h[1]) for h in helps) + 1
    offset = 0
    for key, name in helps:
        stdscr.insstr(height - 1, offset, key)
        stdscr.insstr(height - 1, offset + len(key), name, help_color)
        offset += len(key) + max_len


def set_x_for_yes(x):
    return 'X' if x == 'yes' else ' '


def render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i):
    pool_diff = 2
    longest_net = max(len(net[0]) for net in nets)
    longest_pool = max(len(pool[0]) for pool in pools)
    longest_net = max(longest_net, longest_pool - pool_diff)
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    net_offset = width - longest_net - 9 - pool_diff - 3
    vm_width = net_offset - 3 - 9 - 1 - 2

    vm_table = [("ID", 3, False), ("VM", vm_width - 1, True), ("STATUS", 9, False)]
    net_table = [("NET", longest_net, True), ("STATUS", 8, False), ("A", 1, False), ("P", 1, False)]
    pool_table = [("POOL", longest_net + pool_diff, True), ("STATUS", 8, False), ("A", 1, False)]
    nets = [
        [net[0], net[1], set_x_for_yes(net[2]), set_x_for_yes(net[3])]
        for net in nets
    ]
    pools = [
        [pool[0], pool[1], set_x_for_yes(pool[2])]
        for pool in pools
    ]

    tables = [
        (0, 0, 0, vm_table, lambda vm: vm[2] != "running", vms),
        (1, net_offset, 0, net_table, lambda net: net[1] != "active", nets),
        (2, net_offset, len(nets) + 2, pool_table, lambda pool: pool[1] != "active", pools)
    ]

    head_color = curses.color_pair(2)
    sel_color = curses.color_pair(1)
    for (sel_c, x, y, table, sel_test, items) in tables:
        print_table(stdscr, head_color, sel_color, sel_i if sel == sel_c else -1, x, y, table, sel_test, items)

    print_help(
        stdscr,
        curses.color_pair(1),
        [("TAB", "Next"), ("F1", "Start"), ("F2", "Stop"), ("F10", "Quit")]
    )


def main(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    curses.halfdelay(20)
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()
    curses.init_pair(1, 0, 6)
    curses.init_pair(2, 0, 2)
    curses.init_pair(3, 8, -1)
    curses.init_pair(4, 8, 6)
    sel = 0
    sel_i = 0

    start_commands = ['start', 'net-start', 'pool-start']
    stop_commands = ['destroy', 'net-destroy', 'pool-destroy']

    while True:
        vms = virsh('list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
        nets = virsh('net-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
        pools = virsh('pool-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]

        args = [vms, nets, pools]
        arg_indexes = [1, 0, 0]

        stdscr.clear()
        render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i)
        stdscr.refresh()
        c = stdscr.getch()

        if c == curses.KEY_F10:
            exit()
        elif c == ord('\t'):
            sel = 0 if sel == 2 else sel + 1
        elif c == curses.KEY_DOWN or c == curses.KEY_UP:
            sel_i += -1 if c == curses.KEY_UP else 1
        elif (c == curses.KEY_F1 or c == curses.KEY_F2) and sel_i < len(args[sel]):
            commands = stop_commands if c == curses.KEY_F2 else start_commands
            virsh(commands[sel], args[sel][sel_i][arg_indexes[sel]])

        if sel_i == -1:
            sel_i += 1
        if sel_i >= len(args[sel]):
            sel_i = len(args[sel]) - 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: _Potential religious war_ - Based on the (infamous?) relegation of `reduce` to `functools` and the reasoning for that change, I think you, most of the Python community and I are on the right side of history when it comes to discouraging `map`.

Comment: @Reinderien Indeed. I am trying to to start to mark 'problematic' suggestions. I'm hoping that acknowledging that it's a source for confrontation will help reduce the amount of confrontation I get when a user disregards the advice :)

Comment: At least on my machine this fails to highlight the correct 'machine' (see https://asciinema.org/a/jOrs6moLiwB2Vf2QI6pFaPLWh?t=7). I found the faulty code and reverted it in my answer below.

Comment: @larkey Yeah I noticed that after posting but during changing to `string.Formatter`. I thought I'd added it here, but I didn't. The fix is quite simple really `(sel_i == (i - 1))` because I got the precedence wrong.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Ah, I guessed something like that but was too tired and don't have enough python skill to dig deeper :)  I'll update my answer then!

Answer (score 5):

## Custom Formatter

Half way through [my previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/244398) I decided to integrate Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). I had originally thought there was a lot more formatting going on, but this was not the case. It has a few benefits, but also a few deficits.

Pros:

- It's using syntax that should be in every Python programmers toolbox.
- It forced me to split `print_table` into two functions. Because the formatting was moved inside the class. And then later I moved it out into `select_colors`.
- If you are building more tables it's really quite powerful.

Cons:

- You are unlikely to know this mini-language.
- You're not really using any of the power it brings.
- The method `_cformat` is long and filled with boilerplate.
- You can definitely write the code in fewer lines of code without it.

Whilst it is probably not the best solution for this code it's at least interesting. And can help if you need more advanced formats.

```py
import curses
import enum
import re
import string
import subprocess
import time


class Colours(enum.IntFlag):
    DEFAULT = 0
    GRAY = 1
    SELECT = 2
    HEAD = 4


class CursedFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, stdscr, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stdscr = stdscr
    
    def _cformat(self, format_string, args, kwargs, index=0):
        result = []
        for pre, name, spec, conversion in self.parse(format_string):
            if name is None:
                result.append((pre,))
            else:
                if name == '':
                    if index is False:
                        raise ValueError('cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering')
                    name = str(index)
                    index += 1
                elif name.isdigit():
                    if index:
                        raise ValueError('cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering')
                    index = False
                obj, _ = self.get_field(name, args, kwargs)
                if isinstance(obj, tuple):
                    obj, *a = obj
                else:
                    a = ()
                obj = self.convert_field(obj, conversion)
                spec, index = super()._vformat(spec, args, kwargs, set(), 1, auto_arg_index=index)
                result.append((self.format_field(obj, spec),) + tuple(a))
        return result, index

    def vformat(self, fmt, args, kwargs):
        return ''.join(
            value
            for value, *_ in self._cformat(fmt, args, kwargs)[0]
        )

    def _makestr(self, fn, fmt, args, kwargs):
        values, _ = self._cformat(fmt, args, kwargs)
        x = kwargs.get('x', 0)
        y = kwargs.get('y', 0)
        result = []
        for value in values:
            self._stdscr.insstr(y, x, *value)
            x += len(value[0])
            result.append(value[0])
        return ''.join(result)

    def insstr(self, fmt, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._makestr(self._stdscr.insstr, fmt, args, kwargs)
    
    def addstr(self, fmt, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._makestr(self._stdscr.addstr, fmt, args, kwargs)


def virsh(command, arg):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ['virsh', command, arg],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    out, _ = proc.communicate()
    return [
        [
            x.strip()
            for x in re.split('\\s{2,}', line)
        ]
        for line in re.split('[\r\n]+', out.decode("utf-8"))
    ]


def select_colors(values, sel_i, gray_sel, grays):
    for i, row in enumerate(values):
        gray_row = gray_sel(row)
        new_row = []
        for item, gray in zip(row, grays):
            color = Colours.SELECT if sel_i == i else Colours.DEFAULT
            if gray_row and gray:
                color |= Colours.GRAY
            if i == 0:
                color = Colours.HEAD
            new_row.append((item, curses.color_pair(color)))
        yield new_row


def print_table(stdscr, fmt, values, x, y):
    for i, row in enumerate(values):
        CursedFormatter(stdscr).addstr(fmt, *row, x=x, y=y + i)


def print_help(stdscr, helps):
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    help_color = curses.color_pair(Colours.SELECT)
    CF = CursedFormatter(stdscr)
    CF.insstr('{}', (' ' * width, help_color), x=0, y=height - 1)
    max_len = max(len(h[1]) for h in helps) + 1
    offset = 0
    for key, name in helps:
        CF.insstr('{}{:<{}}', key, (name, help_color), max_len, x=offset, y=height - 1)
        offset += len(key) + max_len


def set_x_for_yes(x):
    return 'X' if x == 'yes' else ' '


def echo(x):
    return x


TABLES = [
    (
        ['ID', 'VM', 'STATUS'],
        [False, True, False],
        [echo, echo, echo],
        lambda vm: vm[2] != 'running',
    ),
    (
        ['NET', 'STATUS', 'A', 'P'],
        [True, False, False, False],
        [echo, echo, set_x_for_yes, set_x_for_yes],
        lambda net: net[1] != "active",
    ),
    (
        ['POOL', 'STATUS', 'A'],
        [True, False, False],
        [echo, echo, set_x_for_yes],
        lambda pool: pool[1] != "active",
    ),
]


def render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i):
    pool_diff = 2
    longest_net = max(len(net[0]) for net in nets)
    longest_pool = max(len(pool[0]) for pool in pools)
    longest_net = max(longest_net, longest_pool - pool_diff)
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    net_offset = width - longest_net - 9 - pool_diff - 3
    vm_width = net_offset - 3 - 9 - 1 - 2

    tables = [
        (
            0,
            0,
            vms,
            (4, vm_width, 10)
        ),
        (
            net_offset,
            0,
            nets,
            (longest_net + 1, 9, 2, 2)
        ),
        (
            net_offset,
            len(nets) + 2,
            pools,
            (longest_net + pool_diff + 1, 9, 2)
        ),
    ]
    for (
        i,
        (
            (x, y, items, widths),
            (header, grays, maps, gray_test)
        ),
    ) in enumerate(zip(tables, TABLES)):
        values = (
            [header]
            + [
                [tran(item) for tran, item in zip(maps, row)]
                for row in items
            ]
        )
        selected = sel_i + 1 if sel == i else -1
        values = select_colors(values, selected, gray_test, grays)
        fmt = ''.join(f'{{:<{width}}}' for width in widths)
        print_table(stdscr, fmt, values, x, y)

    print_help(
        stdscr,
        [("TAB", "Next"), ("F1", "Start"), ("F2", "Stop"), ("F10", "Quit")]
    )


def main(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    curses.halfdelay(20)
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()
    curses.init_pair(Colours.GRAY, 8, -1)
    curses.init_pair(Colours.SELECT, 0, 6)
    curses.init_pair(Colours.SELECT | Colours.GRAY, 8, 6)
    curses.init_pair(Colours.HEAD, 0, 2)
    curses.init_pair(Colours.HEAD | Colours.GRAY, 8, 2)
    sel = 0
    sel_i = 0

    start_commands = ['start', 'net-start', 'pool-start']
    stop_commands = ['destroy', 'net-destroy', 'pool-destroy']

    while True:
        vms = virsh('list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
        nets = virsh('net-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]
        pools = virsh('pool-list', '--all')[2:][:-1]

        args = [vms, nets, pools]
        arg_indexes = [1, 0, 0]

        stdscr.clear()
        render(stdscr, vms, nets, pools, sel, sel_i)
        stdscr.refresh()
        c = stdscr.getch()

        if c == curses.KEY_F10:
            exit()
        elif c == ord('\t'):
            sel = 0 if sel == 2 else sel + 1
        elif c == curses.KEY_DOWN or c == curses.KEY_UP:
            sel_i += -1 if c == curses.KEY_UP else 1
        elif (c == curses.KEY_F1 or c == curses.KEY_F2) and sel_i < len(args[sel]):
            commands = stop_commands if c == curses.KEY_F2 else start_commands
            virsh(commands[sel], args[sel][sel_i][arg_indexes[sel]])

        if sel_i == -1:
            sel_i += 1
        if sel_i >= len(args[sel]):
            sel_i = len(args[sel]) - 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: I don't think I would use the formatter, but it's interesting to see the approach here.

Comment: @DerKommissar Understandable, you should be able to replace it with a very simple function since the format segments, values and colours are all well formed.